# What is the effiiency of these 3 programs (in Python)

Tags: python, performance

I have some functions here and I need to determine the efficiency for them. I tried to figure it out myself first and I have the explanation for my answers below each program.

1.

```
def funct(n):  
    tot = 0
    for i in list(range(0, n, 5)):
      for j in list(range(0, n, n//5)):
        tot = tot + i - j
    return tot
```

Here n is a natural number. I think the efficiency of the program is O(n^2). Because the efficiency is mainly dependent on the for loops. The first for loop is O(n), which is normal for a for loop. The second for loop is still O(n).

2.

```
def funct(L):
  n = len(L)
  tot = 0
  M = []
  for i in L[:n//2]:
    M.append(i)
  for i in L[n//2:]:
    M.extend(L)
  return sum(M)
```

Here L is a list of numbers. I think the efficiency of this one is O(log n). The 2 for loops only loop through half of the list. They are not nested, which means that the efficiency is only O(log n)

3.

```
def fn_f(n):
  n = n % 116
  tot = 0
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n**2):
      tot = tot + 1
  return tot
```

n is a natural number here. Because of the nested for loop, I think the efficiency is O(n^2). But the second for loop is n**2, which means that the efficiency might be exponential. So I think O(2^n) could be right too.

Can someone verify my answer? Thanks :)

Comment: 2. Looping over half the values of `n` still makes the runtime increase linearly in relation to `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correct.
2. The first loop is O(n). In the second loop, `M.extend(L)` is O(n) because it has to copy `L`. This is done `n//2` times, which is O(n). So the second loop is O(n<sup>2</sup>). O(n) + O(n<sup>2</sup>) is O(n<sup>2</sup>).
3. `n = n % 116` limits the value of `n` to `115`. So no matter how big the parameter `n` originally is, the loops are capped to this value. So this function is amortized O(1). If you didn't have that limit, it would be O(n<sup>3</sup>), because the outer loop is O(n) and the inner loop is O(n<sup>2</sup>).